# Google Tag Manager not firing UA

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I inserted GTM script into right place and Tag assistant chrome add-on shows me its working status.

Also, I added UA tag on the working space and It is configured as triggered by all page view event but It is not firing even after I published changes.

Is there anything I miss?

Comment: Can you please show more details about the tags/variables/triggers in question? More information is required to help you out. Screenshots are effective.

Comment: Your setup sounds okay. 
Screenshot will be great to see what you have currently setup.

Comment: Try to use "record" in Tag assistant. If your problem is still actual, please send some screenshots.

Comment: Thank you all. Actually, I got an idea that a CMS might be blocking it. I made inquiries to hosting company. If there other issues, I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a symptom of having the GTM snippet above your dataLayer declaration.